# Simple Ruby puzzle on variable reference in a method

Tags: ruby

Why does this method return 1 rather than dying from infinite recursion?

```
def foo
  foo ||= 1
end

foo # => 1
```

Rewritten the following way it does die:

```
def foo
  foo.nil? ? 1 : foo
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, `foo ||= 1` refers to a local variable. Ruby always creates a local variable when you do assignment on a bareword, which is why you have to write `self.foo = ...` if you want to invoke a writer method defined as `def foo=(value)`. The `||=` operator is, after all, just a fancy assignment operator.

In the second case, there is no assignment, so when it hits `foo.nil?`, Ruby interprets the bareword `foo` as a method call, and blows up.

Comment: Why in the first case and not the second?

Comment: OK, I think it is because in the first case, the ||= is seen by the interpreter first as an assignment rather than as the condition nil?, which makes it interpreted as a local variable rather than a method. -- I see you've added the same explanation.

Comment: Yep, that's it, I updated my answer. [This site](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/variables_and_assignment.html) explains it in some detail.